# is it possible to integrate in a doctrine query a if statement?

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have so far 2 queries which are similar:

the first one I use when user is ROLE_REDAC

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->LeftJoin('a.ArticlePhrases','ap')
        ->addSelect('ap')
        ->where(
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('ap.order', '?1'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('a.author', '?2')
                    )
                )
        ->setParameters(//...
                       );
```

The second one when user is ROLE_ADMIN

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
    $qb->LeftJoin('a.ArticlePhrases','ap')
        ->addSelect('ap')
        ->where(
                $qb->expr()->andX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('ap.order', '?1')
                    )
                )
        ->setParameters(...
                ));
```

There are not much difference. is it possible to call from the controller the same repository fonction and that this fonction adapt whether the actual user is ROLE_REDAC or ROLE_ADM? if yes how can I do that?

Comment: Pass a parameter (user role) to your custom repository function and then, depending on user role, add or not dql code. As easy as that!

Comment: can u please provide an exemple DonCallisto, that would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but should work

```
class MyCustomRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myCustomFunction($user_role)
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a');
        if ($user_role == 'ROLE_REDAC') {
            $where_dql_expr = $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('ap.order', '?1'),
                $qb->expr()->eq('a.author', '?2')
                );
            $qb->setParameters(//....); 
        }
        else if ($user_role == 'ROLE_ADMIN') {
            $where_dql_expr = $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->eq('ap.order', '?1')
            );
            $qb->setParameters(//....); 
        }

        $qb->LeftJoin('a.ArticlePhrases','ap')
           ->addSelect('ap')
           ->where($where_dql_expr)
           ->//and so on
    }
}
```

of course into your controller you have to call it passing the right parameter

```
$role = //retrieve role
$custom_repo = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getManager()
    ->getRepository('YourBundleName:MyCustomEntity');
$custom_repo->myCustomFunction($role);
```